# SUMPRODUCT+ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumproduct

In column E there are 8 formulas that calculate the probability of goal difference between Barcelona and Real Madrid (SUMPRODUCT(A2:A+D3>B2:B)/COUNTA(A2:A)). We need **to replace these 8 formulas with one formula** that will **fill cells E4:E8 automatically**. It is clear that we need to use ARRAYFORMULA, but how to insert cells D3:D10 into it?

File link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3bDILxts1ix8A-KHUqrSty476R9uRd_glsz3Ey-sdk/edit#gid=0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=byrow(D3:D10,lambda(y,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A+y>B2:B)*(A2:A<>""))/COUNTA(A2:A)))
```

Result:

[image]